# How can I insert a 0 if the data in column is starting from 9 and length is 10 in python

Tags: python

I have an issue regarding the correction of number .. i want all the mobile number will start as 09,
just like this 09123456711 and telephone number will also add office code using excel reference file

[image]

```
import pandas
import re
#import lambda 


excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\Ben Projects\MCC RPA\endoProcess\attachments\Book1.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet1')

excel_data_df['phone1']=excel_data_df['phone1'].replace('\/','',regex=True)
excel_data_df['phone2']=excel_data_df['phone2'].replace('\/','',regex=True)
excel_data_df['phone3']=excel_data_df['phone3'].replace('\/','',regex=True)

#print(excel_data_df)

for val in excel_data_df['phone1']:
    #print(val)
    if(len(val) == 10 and val[0][:1] == "9"):
       #for i in val:
        excel_data_df.at[val,'phone1'] = str(val).zfill(11)
        #excel_data_df['phone2']
        print(excel_data_df)

    else:
        print("no")


    excel_data_df.to_excel("C:/Users/User/Documents/Ben Projects/MCC RPA/endoProcess/attachments/Book3.xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Phone'] = df['Phone'].apply(lambda x: '0' + str(x) if (len(str(x)) == 10 and str(x).startswith('9')) else str(x))
```

This line converts all rows of column `Phone` into strings and if length of string is 10 chars and it starts with '9', appends '0' at the start

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add a zero manually?

Say the phone number you get from Excel is `9123456711`.

```
number = '9123456711'
if number[0] != str(0):
   number = '0' + number
print(number)
```

and you get

```
09123456711
```

Comment: how about thos number which is not phone number

Comment: Is your list a mixture of phone number and non phone numbers? How do you know which one is which on Excel?

Comment: Those number which start of 03 will stay remain and only those number who start in 9

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You want to leave the numbers that start in '03' unchages, and only add the '0' in front of the ones which start with '9'?

Comment: I want to leave the numbers that start in '03' unchages, and only the number that start to 9 will have the leading 0

Comment: That's exactly what I am doing. If the number starts with '0', it is not picked up by the `If`statement.

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to make the `0` a string. Should work now.